# How to paste information from JSON Helper

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm able to fetch JSON data using [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSONHelper.html) and see the results in Script Editor, under Results.  I'm not sure what I would use next in AppleScript to copy those results so I can paste it into a program such as Numbers.

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set myRecord to fetch JSON from "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json"
    return myRecord
end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `set the clipboard to` command.

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set myRecord to fetch JSON from "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json"
    set the clipboard to (make JSON from myRecord)
end tell
```

Comment: Can I ask you, is there other options in copying the Json data, instead of "myRecord"  I simply used that one because their was an example provided using it.